# Although I have compiled my Keras Sequential model , I am getting RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it

Tags: python, keras, runtime-error

I am trying to code an image caption generator using the CNN-RNN model. For the RNN part, I create my own class `CaptionGenerator` one of whose methods `create_model` (shown below) creates two sequential models-image model and language model and concatenates them. After that I compile the model.

```
def create_model(self, ret_model = False):

    image_model = Sequential()
    image_model.add(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM, input_dim = 4096, activation='relu'))
    image_model.add(RepeatVector(self.max_cap_len))

    lang_model = Sequential()
    lang_model.add(Embedding(self.vocab_size, 256, input_length=self.max_cap_len))
    lang_model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))
    lang_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM)))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Concatenate([image_model, lang_model]))
    model.add(LSTM(1000,return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(self.vocab_size))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    if(ret_model==True):
        return model

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

In another file, I create an object of this class using which I create an object of the above model.

```
def train_model(weight = None, batch_size=32, epochs = 10):
    cg = caption_generator.CaptionGenerator()
    model = cg.create_model()

    if weight != None:
        model.load_weights(weight)

    counter = 0
    file_name = 'weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}.hdf5'
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(file_name, monitor='loss', verbose=1, 
                 save_best_only=True, mode='min')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    print(" Fitting the data ") 
    model.fit_generator(cg.data_generator(batch_size=batch_size), 
                        steps_per_epoch=cg.total_samples/batch_size, 
                        epochs=epochs, verbose=2, 
                        callbacks=callbacks_list)
    try:
        model.save('Models/WholeModel.h5', overwrite=True)
        model.save_weights('Models/Weights.h5',overwrite=True)
    except:
        print ( "Error in saving model." )
    print ( "Training complete...\n" )
```

But when I am calling the `function model.fit_generator()`, I am getting the following error although the model has been compiled in `create_model` method of `CaptionGenerator` class:

```
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

[Error Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otXQD.png)

[Model Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgqOg.png)

Comment: When you use the method with `ret_model=True` it returns the model before compiling it. That could be the problem but without seeing the definition of the method or the error stack trace it's difficult to give a more precise answer

Comment: @LucBlassel I have uploaded the images of error stack and model architecture.

Comment: @Shibam Basu you should check is your code uses actual versions of imported moduels, for example, `caption_generator`. This code returns compiled model, however there are some other errors - at least Concatenate can't work correctly this way, is't designed for a [functional](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) API.

Comment: @MikhailStepanov Yes,the code imports the actual version of the `caption_generator` class .Can you please suggest how to merge the image model and language model according to the model architecture (image link of architecture given above) ? I am unable to find out why its telling me to compile the model although it has already been compiled.